# GetProperty() of object returns null

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to check if the yAxis object of each ChartObject holds the property MajorGridlines. I have written the following code:

```
foreach (ChartObject chartObject in chartObjects) {
     yAxis = chartObject.Chart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue);

     if (yAxis.GetType().GetProperty("MajorGridlines", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) != null)
     {
          return true; //Do stuff with the gridlines
     }
     else
     {
          return false; //MajorGridlines property does not exist for yAxis, so don't try to do stuff with gridlines
     }
}
```

**Since chartObject changes with each iteration, so does the yAxis object. I think the issue has to do with that.**

MajorGridlines does indeed seem to be a property of yAxis. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Thankful for any help on this.

Comment: Please post the Property declaration as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Can you please clarify? Axis.MajorGridlines is part of interop.excel if that's what you mean, I did not create the property myself.

Comment: Try debug and print `yAxis.GetType().Name` and the values of `string.Join(", ", obj.GetType().GetProperties().Select(prop => prop.Name))`

Comment: `yAxis.GetType().Name` returns __ComObject. the string.join doesn't return anything for me

Comment: I have updated my question after realizing the code works for a string object, but not for an object I'm iterating over. Does this give you any guidance? @OrelEraki

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell reflection that the BindingFlags you're looking for are `Instance` or `Static`

e.g for property which is part of the instance:

```
yAxis.GetType().GetProperty("MajorGridlines", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) != null)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. However it doesn't solve my problem. It still returns false.